# Cannot stop element overlap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, overlapping

I recently created a blog with the help of Wordpress, i got myself a standard theme and edited this into something i like.

Now i only have 1 issue and that is whenever you shrink the window and it reaches about half of the screen stuff starts to overflow because the header and picture inside the posts won't resize any further with it.

I tried googling so many solutions, tried so many but i cannot get it to work.

If anyone could help me find out what i should have and where i should put it, it would save me ><

You can see the website at [Link](http://www.sallysubs.com)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about setting the `max-width` property on resize?

Comment: Where would i do that exactly?

Comment: In your css of the image ;)

Comment: Well i already tried putting the max-width attribute everywhere that involved the header and images, it just never works.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the page from resizing, or are you trying to make the header and other elements scale right as you resize?

Comment: I wanted them to scale with everything, although i'm not sure if making everything stop at one point might be better.

Comment: I want everything to keep resizing as the size further decreases, anyone?